# Can we runn mobile app tests in headless appium on a Physical Device (Non emulator)?

Tags: android, appium, native, appium-android, headless

I am not able to run headless on a physical device and even tried by using below code

```
 capabilities.setCapability("isHeadless", true);
      capabilities.setCapability("avdArgs", "-no-window");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run Appium tests in `headless` mode on physical devices for either Android/iOS. What `headless` does for emulators/simulators is to just hide their GUI, which you cannot do on a real device. What's more is that `avdArgs` capability will never work on a real device, not only for `no-window` but in general, because what this capability targets is contained in its name `avd = Android Virtual Device`